# Blade Template wildcard url to match

Tags: php, laravel, wildcard, laravel-blade

Got a quick question how do i make a string respond to a wildcard like so:

```
<h4 class="onePRO-heading pull-left"><strong>Example</strong>
     @if (URL::current() === 'http://example.com.au' .(:any) .)
     :SSO
     @endif

</h4>
```

So if the url is example.com or example.com/sign-in etc it will be true.

I am trying not to manualy enter all urls

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you process the URL before making the comparison?  Something like this:

```
<h4 class="onePRO-heading pull-left"><strong>Example</strong>
     @if ( parse_url(URL::current())['host'] == 'example.com.au' )
     :SSO
     @endif

</h4>
```

[`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) returns an array of the various parts of the URL.. it allows us to extract the `host` before making the comparison...